# What is the best architecture to secure traffic between compute engine and app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, network-programming, google-compute-engine

We have a HTTP communication currently in between an app engine and a compute engine. What would be the best way secure the communication without providing a secure layer at the HTTP.

Are there native Google functionalities that are well suited - any VPC configuration, VPN technologies, peering? What would you recommend we start to explore?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, an approach could depend on where are your App Engine and Compute Engine instances located: are they part of the same or different projects, reside in the same or different zone or region, do they communicate via Internal or External IP.

Google uses authentication, integrity checks and  AS128 encryption to protect data at one or more network layers when that data goes outside physical boundaries not controlled by Google. 
Data in transit inside a physical boundary controlled by Google is not necessarily encrypted because rigorous physical security measures are in place by default, but authentication and integrity are always applied.

More details can be found in the document [Encryption in Transit in Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-in-transit).

Next, it'd be good to figure out what security risks you expect regarding your data in transit. Speaking about risks, potential vulnerabilities and threats as well as their probability and feasibility should be assessed. For example, for the data transferred between two services communicating via Internal IPs in the same subnetwork of the same zone, threats and vulnerabilities are quite limited compared to public network.

In case the security requirements are so high that the underlying network can't be trusted, Google VPC and VPN go beyond the scope, and you have to encrypt at the Level 7. That is why using HTTPS seems like a logical solution in this case.

Comment: The two services are in the same project and the same zone. They communicate via internal IP. Can you clarify what you mean by "Google VPC and VPN go beyond the scope"

Comment: "In case the security requirements are so high that the underlying network can't be trusted". Usually it belongs to public networks, but we don't know specific requirements of your project and "what security risks you expect".